# Is there a more efficient way of getting data from 5 tables other than what I am doing now?

Tags: c#, mysql, select, join

So what I am trying to do is to put accumulative data on a ListView object using C# and then get the tally of sales for a sales report. As you can see it is very unstable, my code that is, and I mainly want to remove having to invoke two MySqlCommands and DataReaders. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

```
string query = "SELECT * FROM orderlist ol "+
               "INNER JOIN orderdb o "+
               "ON ol.order_ID = o.order_ID "+
               "INNER JOIN menudb m "+
               "ON ol.menu_ID = m.menu_ID "+   
               "WHERE o.order_date >= '"+fromdate.Date()+"' AND "+
                     "o.order_date <= '"+todate.Date()+"'";
command = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
dr = command.ExecuteReader();
string[] info = new string[15];
while(dr.Read())
{
  string query2 = "SELECT r.*, s.stock_pricePerPiece FROM recipelist r "+
                  "INNER JOIN stocksdb s ON r.stock_ID = s.stock_ID "+
                  "WHERE r.menu_ID = '"+(dr["menu_ID"].ToString())+"'";
  MySqlCommand cmd2 = new MySqlCommand(query2, connection2);
  MySqlDataReader dr2 = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
  double menu_cost = 0;
  while(dr2.Read())
  {
      menu_cost += Convert.ToDouble(dr2["stock_pricePerPiece"].ToString());
  }

info[1] = (dr["order_ID"].ToString());
info[2] = (dr["order_date"].ToString());
info[3] = (dr["menu_name"].ToString());
info[4] = (menu_cost.ToString("#0.00"));
info[5] = (dr["menu_price"].ToString());
info[6] = (Convert.ToDouble(info[5]) - menu_cost).ToString("#0.00");
this.ReportList.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new string[] { info[1] , info[2] , info[3] , info[4] , info[5] , info[6] }));
}
```

Comment: I think I should also say that `THE CODE IS UNTESTED` and is made prior to asking the question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this in one query. You can `JOIN` them like so:

```
SELECT 
  r.* 
FROM  orderlist ol 
INNER JOIN orderdb    o ON ol.order_ID = o.order_ID
INNER JOIN menudb     m ON ol.menu_ID  = m.menu_ID
INNER JOIN recipelist r ON r.menu_ID   = m.menu_ID
INNER JOIN stocksdb   s ON r.stock_ID  = s.stock_ID 
WHERE o.order_date >= ...
  AND o.order_date <= ...;
```

---

**Update:** To select the total `menu_cost`, which is the total cost of all the stock items used on a menu:

```
SELECT 
  s.menu_cost,
  ...
FROM  orderlist ol 
INNER JOIN orderdb    o ON ol.order_ID = o.order_ID
INNER JOIN menudb     m ON ol.menu_ID  = m.menu_ID
INNER JOIN recipelist r ON r.menu_ID   = m.menu_ID
INNER JOIN
( 
   SELECT stock_ID, SUM(stock_pricePerPiece) menu_cost
   FROM stocksdb 
   GROUP BY stock_ID
)  s ON r.stock_ID  = s.stock_ID 
WHERE o.order_date >= ...
  AND o.order_date <= ...;
```

Comment: how about the `menu_cost` which is the total cost of all the stock items used on a `menu`? how do you get that in a singe query like this?

Comment: @JohnErnestGuadalupe - Where it is? I can't see it in your code.

Comment: @JohnErnestGuadalupe Sorry, Just saw it so, from which table this cast is coming from? and it is per menu or per stock?

Comment: the `stock_pricePerPiece` is from the `stocksdb` and it is per stock where each stock are used on different menus. I hope I am not too confusing :D sorry

Comment: @JohnErnestGuadalupe See my edit. I am not sure for this, may be you will need to use a group by.

Comment: I don't know what group by does, but what does the `s` do right before `ON r.stock_ID = s.stock_ID`?

Comment: I am getting an `Index was outside the bounds of the array` error on `dr = command.ExecuteReader()`

Comment: @JohnErnestGuadalupe `s` is an alias for the subquery inside the `INNER JOIN`. For the error, don't make two while loops for reading the results, you will need only one while loop for reading from the data reader. Also try the query directly on the management studio and ensure that it works correctly and its results are what you are looking for.

Comment: I didn't. I only have one while loop.

Comment: I did it, it doesn't get the menu_cost

Comment: @JohnErnestGuadalupe - Can you please update your question with the code that give you that error? Did you try it directly and works fine?

Comment: I managed to do it with a few tweaks :) thanks a lot for the help man :)

Answer (score 1):

```
string query = "SELECT ol.*, " + 
           "(SELECT SUM(stock_pricePerPiece) FROM recipelist r INNER JOIN stocksdb s ON r.stock_ID = s.stock_ID WHERE r.menu_ID = ol.menu_ID ) " +
           "AS stock_pricePerPiece FROM orderlist ol "+
           "INNER JOIN orderdb o "+
           "ON ol.order_ID = o.order_ID "+
           "INNER JOIN menudb m "+
           "ON ol.menu_ID = m.menu_ID "+ 
           "WHERE o.order_date >= '"+fromdate.Date()+"' AND "+
                 "o.order_date <= '"+todate.Date()+"'";
```

and get the menu_cost from the first data reader, you don't need the 2nd data reader

```
menu_cost =  Convert.ToDouble(dr["stock_pricePerPiece"].ToString());
```

Comment: actually the second data reader adds all the stock's `stock_pricePerPiece` where they are used on the same menu having the same `menu_ID`. How do you get that in a single query?

Comment: I am getting an `index was outside the bound of the array` error on my `dr = command.ExecuteReader()`?

Answer (score 1):

The way your doing it can cause you a real performance issues, Creating dynamically SQL's and executing them is not really effecient since they are expensive in time, you should leave this job to the DBMS, use [joins](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp) or [views](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_view.asp) to build your desired data set and let your database manage this, then execute one single statement, you will feel the difference in a large amount of data.

Just for the case you are interested you can generate the [execution plan](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/execution-plan-information.html) of your query to see how performant is it, dont know about mysql but other DBMS's like SQLServer offer you even optimization steps to achive the same results with a better performance.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the SQL query I have made based on the accumulated answers. I just think I should share it with you guys. Thanks a lot for the answers!

```
SELECT 
DISTINCT o.order_ID, o.order_date, o.order_status, m.*, mc.menu_cost
FROM  orderlist ol 
INNER JOIN orderdb    o ON ol.order_ID = o.order_ID
INNER JOIN menudb     m ON ol.menu_ID  = m.menu_ID
INNER JOIN
(SELECT SUM(s.stock_pricePerPiece * r.recipe_quantity) AS menu_cost, m.menu_ID
    FROM recipelist r
        INNER JOIN stocksdb s ON r.stock_ID = s.stock_ID
        INNER JOIN menudb m ON r.menu_ID= m.menu_ID
    GROUP BY r.menu_ID
) 
mc ON m.menu_ID = mc.menu_ID
WHERE o.order_date >= '2012-12-22 00:00:00'
  AND o.order_date <= '2012-12-22 23:59:59';
```